# How to get an object with django serializer the contains Foreignkey ids WITHOUT execution of queries to every referenced object

Tags: django, django-views, django-serializer

I'm really new to Django, but one in our projects we have a Django backend, and no one else would like to touch it, so I have to make little tweaks on that. Models set up, everything work fine, but we need a new view, where we need basic data about one of our models, without referenced models (only the foreign key id is needed). I've got a solution from SO before, but while that solution returns the prefered result, still executes a tons of queries in the background. Every referenced object is queried for every returned object, meanwhile we need only their ids/keys.

Meanwhile I've modified serializer as trinchet mentioned, but that didn't helped. Still tons of queries.

Models:

```
class Row(models.Model):
    row = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    height = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Column(models.Model):
    col = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    width = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Column, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Product(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique = True)

    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, db_column='column_key', to_field='key', related_name="products")
    row  = models.ForeignKey(Row, db_column='row_key', to_field='key', related_name="products")
    merged_with = models.ForeignKey("Product", db_column='merged_with_key', to_field='key', related_name="merges", blank=True, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class SimpleProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'key', 'text', 'row', 'column', 'merged_with')

    row = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only = True)
    column = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only = True)
    merged_with = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only = True)
```

The result is a simple json, that contains the pure product object array:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    key: "1746495d-8ea0-42df-9ed9-06df621ef7c5",
    column_key: "<key of refrenced column>"
    key: "1746495d-8ea0-42df-9ed9-06df621ef7c5"
    merged_with_key: "<key of refrenced product>"
    row_key: "<key of refrenced row>"
    text: "sometext"
}, .....]
```

But in the backend, huge amount of queries have been executed to retreive columns/rows for every product object.

```
DEBUG 2017-03-18 11:27:27,704 utils 424 140142129104640 (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_product"."id", "dashboard_product"."dashboard_id", "dashboard_product".
"key", "dashboard_product"."text", "dashboard_product"."column_key", "dashboard_produc
t"."row_key", "dashboard_product"."merged_with_key" FROM "dashboard_product" WHERE "dashboard_product"."key" IN ('2a578e00-af19-4b3d-a
65f-5bf9daf490f7', '29c571bc-fb58-42b6-8721-edb8a96cc682', '6fb9ed7a-0e4f-4c06-95d3-15f16d281247', 'b6aa4aa3-be47-4641-a79b-1eddc3e4d28d', '026ea99a-75cd
-4708-adbd-117aef19a159', '86f49c57-1ba4-4b63-aadb-01eb95984306', 'f4a2f175-afa2-4337-891a-fce15ceaab1b', 'c31f2244-3e44-4c7e-b68a-997a0c25426f', 'cb2656
c3-7515-443a-8217-45e8a4e32d42', NULL, 'a801e609-49a2-46bb-9fad-453e9ebc6143', '2e2c85ae-bd60-43ae-9b6c-00988e69d470', '54165d95-ced7-4e28-b6e8-6c604f094
808', '74bda05f-5bf3-47ec-bbb0-b16eaf1839ec'); args=('2a578e00-af19-4b3d-a65f-5bf9daf490f7', '29c571bc-fb58-42b6-8721-edb8a96cc682', '6fb9ed7a-0e4f-4c06-
95d3-15f16d281247', 'b6aa4aa3-be47-4641-a79b-1eddc3e4d28d', '026ea99a-75cd-4708-adbd-117aef19a159', '86f49c57-1ba4-4b63-aadb-01eb95984306', 'f4a2f175-afa
2-4337-891a-fce15ceaab1b', 'c31f2244-3e44-4c7e-b68a-997a0c25426f', 'cb2656c3-7515-443a-8217-45e8a4e32d42', None, 'a801e609-49a2-46bb-9fad-453e9ebc6143',
'2e2c85ae-bd60-43ae-9b6c-00988e69d470', '54165d95-ced7-4e28-b6e8-6c604f094808', '74bda05f-5bf3-47ec-bbb0-b16eaf1839ec')

DEBUG 2017-03-18 11:27:27,712 utils 424 140142129104640 (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_row"."id", "dashboard_row"."dashboard_id", "dashboard_row"."row", "dash
board_row"."height", "dashboard_row"."key" FROM "dashboard_row" WHERE "dashboard_row"."key" = '905bd277-3a31-4361-8877-dc3c019aff29'; args=('905bd277-3a3
1-4361-8877-dc3c019aff29',)

DEBUG 2017-03-18 11:27:27,717 utils 424 140142129104640 (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_column"."id", "dashboard_column"."dashboard_id", "dashboard_column"."co
l", "dashboard_column"."width", "dashboard_column"."key" FROM "dashboard_column" WHERE "dashboard_column"."key" = '4633a6a0-4532-4681-851e-562c1e409b15';
 args=('4633a6a0-4532-4681-851e-562c1e409b15',)

DEBUG 2017-03-18 11:27:27,720 utils 424 140142129104640 (0.000) SELECT "dashboard_row"."id", "dashboard_row"."dashboard_id", "dashboard_row"."row", "dash
board_row"."height", "dashboard_row"."key" FROM "dashboard_row" WHERE "dashboard_row"."key" = '905bd277-3a31-4361-8877-dc3c019aff29'; args=('905bd277-3a3
1-4361-8877-dc3c019aff29',)

DEBUG 2017-03-18 11:27:27,722 utils 424 140142129104640 (0.000) SELECT "dashboard_column"."id", "dashboard_column"."dashboard_id", "dashboard_column"."co
l", "dashboard_column"."width", "dashboard_column"."key" FROM "dashboard_column" WHERE "dashboard_column"."key" = 'e30ea177-3819-4b57-b725-6d89b207d740';
 args=('e30ea177-3819-4b57-b725-6d89b207d740',)

DEBUG 2017-03-18 11:27:27,724 utils 424 140142129104640 (0.000) SELECT "dashboard_row"."id", "dashboard_row"."dashboard_id", "dashboard_row"."row", "dash
board_row"."height", "dashboard_row"."key" FROM "dashboard_row" WHERE "dashboard_row"."key" = '6a5a9e1a-9098-430a-985a-81c61e29f3db'; args=('6a5a9e1a-909
8-430a-985a-81c61e29f3db',)
... etc
```

How to block this behaviour, to execute only one query, that returns the product objects, and doesn't reach out for references, that we don't use. It's a serious performance bottleneck now, and i've spent long hours to find a solution to this. 
I have solved that using json serializers, but they can't handle Array fields, and have some other issues also. There must be a more elegant way, to solve this problem.

br,

Csaba

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple stuff:

1. Defining, explicitly, a [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) field in your `SimpleProductSerializer` serializer for each ForeignKey, or
2. Use [`select_related/prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) in the queryset you pass to the `SimpleProductSerializer`.

Both of them will eliminate the no-needed queries, but in the second case, you will get some data (in the query) you won't need (entire related objects instead just the IDs)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I've tried your solution (also modified the original post) with PrimaryKeyRelatedFields, but that didn't helped. Still lots of queries. Do you have any other idea?